# If condition takes only the first case in Unix

Tags: arrays, unix, if-statement, ksh

I've got an array with some values inside it. I have to check the values and move accordingly. This is my code.

```
    var=$EOR
    if [ "${arr[0]}" != "NUMBER" ];
    then
      FIELD1=`echo $var | awk 'BEGIN { f="'"'"'" } {split($0,x,/@#/); printf "%s\n", f     x[1] f}'`   #output: 'field1'
    else
      FIELD1=`echo $var | awk '{ split($0,x,"@#"); print x[1]}'`   
    fi #output: field1
```

So, if the array at position 0 is not `NUMBER` the first field of a file will be written between quotes, else not. The problem is that seems to takes only the first condition and the output is `'field1'` although the first array value is an `NUMBER`. Something wrong?

Comment: You'd have to show some `ksh -x` trace output to be convincing, or otherwise show how `${arr[0]}` is not NUMBER and yet the code is doing the wrong thing.  Frankly, I think it unlikely you'll be able to demonstrate that; shells are very well tested bits of code.

Comment: `set -vx` is your friend. Good luck.

Comment: you have a ridiculous assumption. search the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Where and how precisely do you set $arr ?